# Linux shell : Interactive Fuzzy-Search content in files using grep and fzf

Tags: grep, fzf

I want to write a shell script that search for a pattern inside all the files in a specific directory (say, my '.config' folder).
Using grep I wrote the following:

```
grep -Ril "<pattern>" .config
```

Next I was trying to change the search pattern on the fly using something like:

```
grep -Ril "" .config | fzf --preview='<preview> {}'
```

, but since I'm passing the filename to fzf - I can only filter the results by names...

Basiclly I'm looking for something like:

```
grep -Ril "<fzf_pattern>" .config | fzf --preview='<preview> {}'
```

Comment: You might want to create an issue on the `fzf` repo and ask this question. The developer might help you out :)

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples#searching-file-contents fuzzy search content of a file.

Comment: You want to check this out: https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep fuzzy search files, directories, compressed archives etc. Just execute `ugrep -Ril -Z "<pattern>" .config`

Comment: There is no "Linux Shell", you're probably using Ash or Bash, but there are many other shells and many of them work on other kernels, not just Linux.

Answer (score 2):

see this little [script](https://gist.github.com/TripleDogDare/170cf93be8f4bd1f5dcbef26ad41246b) which you can name as `fzgrep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
# go get github.com/junegunn/fzf

BEFORE=10
AFTER=10
HEIGHT=$(expr $BEFORE + $AFTER + 3 )  # 2 lines for the preview box and 1 extra line fore the match

PREVIEW="$@ 2>&1 | grep --color=always -B${BEFORE} -A${AFTER} -F -- {}"

"$@" 2>&1 | fzf --height=$HEIGHT --reverse --preview="${PREVIEW}"
```

and use it as follows: `fzgrep cat /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
grep -R "$(find .config/* -type f -exec cat {} \; | fzf)" .config/
```