# How to launch fzf text search with context preview?

Tags: fzf

When I pipe text into fzf how can I make it display search preview which includes context around the search match so that it works like live `grep -C5 text` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux shell : Interactive Fuzzy-Search content in files using grep and fzf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60024348/linux-shell-interactive-fuzzy-search-content-in-files-using-grep-and-fzf)

Comment: hi @jackhab, see my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76153099/9109880

Comment: @giulianopz Thanks but it does not answer -  I was asking about fzf, not about Bash scripting.